# How to crop from Top & Bottom of Video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms

[image]I would like to crop a video strip from top as well as bottom in Video Sequence Editor.  When I tried by checking the "offset" check box and the "crop" box, I am able to crop from the top, but when I crop from the bottom the whole image moves. I do this in other video Editors but I could not figure out how it can be done in Blender VSE.

Thank you.

[image: Crop after]

Comment: you need to uncheck offset, then crop the top and the bottom. Once that's done work out the height of the resulting video by adding both crops together and subtracting that number from the original video height and then enter that as Resolution Y in the Output Properties. Hope that's more or less clear :)

Comment: What if I need to fully close the black bars with keyframes?

Comment: by keyframes do you mean you want to animate it?

Comment: Yes.Like in this video. Below link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXY17uJmcKf3zAdx9qLOglWV7JQpQZZF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can't get the file, can you make it public access? or put a couple of screenshot (before/after)? but from what I understand you might have to zoom in the picture and also cut from left and right to keep the same aspect ratio

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I have added a picture which can be called roughly as "after" ,but I have not closed the black bars fully because then the pic would be fully black.

Comment: thanks, then i had totally misunderstood your question! gonna look at what's the easiest way to do that

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this effect is to animate the Y offset in sync with the bottom crop.
So enable Crop and Offset and insert a keyframe with 0 value for `Offset > Position Y`, `Crop Top` and `Crop Bottom` where you want the animation to start.
Divide your video's height by 2 then go to the frame when you want the animation to finish and insert a keyframe at that same value for all three fields.
Done!

Comment: Thank you very much. It's done. It's not difficult.Thank you again.

Comment: great, glad it helped! you can accept the answer